# Update Common field in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 10 tables, all belongs to user, so user_id is present in all tables, there is another field 'company_id' present in tables.

Now I want to hand over some of user's associations to another user.

Individual queries:

```
Update table1 set user_id = XX where user_id = YY and company_id = ZZ
Update table2 set user_id = XX where user_id = YY and company_id = ZZ
Update table3 set user_id = XX where user_id = YY and company_id = ZZ
.
.
```

so on...
is it possible to do it in one query?

Comment: you could make a stored procedure for that

Answer (score 0):

If the user_id and company_id are consistent in your 10 updates, you could abstract them into local variables (you may already be doing this)

`DECLARE @olduser BIGINT, @newuser BIGINT, @company BIGINT
    UPDATE table1 SET user_id = @newuser WHERE user_id = @olduser and company_id = @company
    UPDATE table2 SET user_id = @newuser WHERE user_id = @olduser and company_id = @company
    ...`

This is the closest I think you can get to a single statement other than a stored procedure as previously mentioned.  Is there a reason you NEED it to be in "one statement"?

Just because the columns share the same name, the columns are still stored as separate objects and the computer has to be told explicitly which table each column belongs to.

Comment: I going to update large database. so, to decrease server down time I was looking for fast queries, So I was looking for the "one statement"